# How to show symbol § when I refer a chapter

Tags: symbols

I'm writing my thesis and I would like that the reference of the chapters, sections, etc... appears with symbol §, e.g.:

...as can be seen in §4.1.1

What package or reference/label combination do I need to use?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of packages do you use that could influence the referencing of `\label`s? [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)? [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref)? Something else? Ideal you should provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that contains all such information and nothing more; something we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and replicate your problem.

Comment: See also [How to reference a paragraph with § symbol and without a dot?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63278/5001) While the immediate topic of that posting is how to use the `§` for paragraph-level headers, the code is easily transferred to chapter- and section-level headers.

Comment: You can do this easily by \S

Answer (score 28):

You can get automatically the § symbol (which I don't recommend, though) with `cleveref` and its `\cref` command.

It's better to have a different command than `\ref`, because you might need the latter for referring the section without the § prefix. The § symbol is obtained with `\S`.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{hyperref} % not needed; should go before cleveref if loaded
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{section}{\S#2#1#3} % see manual of cleveref, section 8.2.1
\crefformat{subsection}{\S#2#1#3}
\crefformat{subsubsection}{\S#2#1#3}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}\label{sec:section}

\subsection{A subsection}\label{sec:subsection}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\label{sec:subsubsection}

See \cref{sec:section}, \cref{sec:subsection} or \cref{sec:subsubsection}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also format multiple references; here's a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{hyperref} % not needed; should go before cleveref if loaded
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{section}{\S#2#1#3}
\crefformat{subsection}{\S#2#1#3}
\crefformat{subsubsection}{\S#2#1#3}
\crefrangeformat{section}{\S\S#3#1#4 to~#5#2#6}
\crefmultiformat{section}{\S\S#2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}\label{sec:section}

\subsection{A subsection}\label{sec:subsection}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\label{sec:subsubsection}

\section{Another}\label{sec:another}

\section{Again}\label{sec:again}

See \cref{sec:section}, \cref{sec:subsection} or \cref{sec:subsubsection}.

See \cref{sec:section,sec:another,sec:again}

See \cref{sec:again,sec:section}

See \cref{sec:again,sec:subsection}

See \cref{sec:subsection,sec:subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe that it's conventional to employ `§§` as the plural of `§` when using these symbols as the "names" of sectioning headers. If one uses `\crefformat` for the singular case, as you do in the example code, one also needs to use `\crefmultiformat` to set up the plural case. For the example at hand, it may be easier to employ `\crefname{section}{\S}{\S\S}`, etc.

Comment: @Mico With `\crefname` there would be a space between § and the number.

Comment: @egreg Which would be correct if you write a Norwegian legal text.

Comment: You could also add \crefrangemultiformat{section}{\S\S#3#1#4 to~#5#2#6}{ and~#3#1#4 to~#5#2#6}{, #3#1#4 to~#5#2#6}{ and~#3#1#4 to~#5#2#6} if you want to edit the ranges in multireferences.

Answer (score 6):

It may be best to define a new command, say `\secref` that you use for references to sectional units, while using `\ref` for everything else:

```
\newcommand{\secref}[1]{\S\ref{#1}}
```

`hyperref` provides this functionality via its `\autoref` feature. You merely have to define the `\<counter>autorefname` macros accordingly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{\S}
\renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{\S}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{\S}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\label{sec:section}
\subsection{A subsection}\label{sec:subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\label{sec:subsubsection}
See \autoref{sec:section}, \autoref{sec:subsection} or \autoref{sec:subsubsection}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The only problem I have with your solution is that if I use it, I get the symbol before each reference (i.e. Figures, Tables...) and I only want it before chapters,sections,etc...

Comment: @user64993: If you're willing to use a designated macro (like `\secref`), this can be avoided. [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) does something similar through `\autoref`. See my updated answer above. [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) has similar functionality, although I didn't include that in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I used the [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/) website to search the sign you are asking.

[image]

```
%pdflatex
\documentclass[margin=0.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
\textsection
\end{document}
```

The usage is simple, just assign a reference tag to the chapter you want, and then add that reference tag besides to this sign in your text. Please read the following page:

> Wikibooks contributors, "LaTeX/Labels and Cross-referencing,"
>   Wikibooks, The Free Textbook Project,
>   http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing&oldid=2673141
>   (accessed October 25, 2014).

[image]

```
%pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\section{my chapter} 
\label{chapter}
This is my example chapter.

\section{my other chapter}
Please read the first content on \textsection \ref{chapter}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: No need to load the `textcomp` package to access the `§` symbol -- `\S` suffices.